# GCC Struct Doublepointer array init

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, struct

I'm programming something with c and compile it with gcc on ubuntu. I defined on the Struct a double pointer "mark" for an 2 dimensional Array (for a chessboard ). I have to defined it with a double pointer and I'm not allowed to do it with a matrix or something else. I initialized it with a function. It goes right but for any reasons I can't adress mark[0][0]. If i printed the value out i'm getting a very big and wrong value. I debugged it with gdb and found out that at i=4;k=2 the value of mark[0][0] gets wrong, also I cannot rewrite the value, if i do so I'm getting an memory error. Can someone help me here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct t_brett{
    //Boardsize
    int n;  
    //Double Pointer for 2-dimensional Array
        int **mark; 
    //number of jump
    int lsgnr;
    //position of the knight Springers
    int x;
    int y;
}t_brett;


int init_brett(struct t_brett *b, int n, int x, int y){
    b->n=n;
    b->lsgnr=2;
    b->x=x-1; b->y=y-1;
    //first Dimension of Array
    b->mark=malloc(sizeof(int)*n+1); 
    int i,k;    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            //second Dimension of Array 
        b->mark[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*n+1);
        //Init Values: mit 0
        for(k=0;k<n;k++){ 
                b->mark[i][k]=0;
        }
    }
    b->mark[0][0]=0;
    return 0;
}

Method for print: for lines with +----+----+
void gitter(struct t_brett *b){
    int i;
    printf("+");
    for(i=0;i<b->n;i++){
            printf("---+");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Method for print: for lines with +  9+  8+
void gitter_zahl(int j,struct t_brett *b){
    int i;
    printf("+");
    for(i=0;i<b->n;i++){
            printf(" %2d+",b->mark[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print(struct t_brett *b){
    int i; int j=0;
    //printf("+");
    for(i=0;i<b->n;i++){
            gitter(b);
            gitter_zahl(j, b);
            j++;
    }
    gitter(b);
}

int main(){
    struct t_brett b;
    if (init_brett(&b,5, 5, 1)>0) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    print(&b);
}
```

My Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
+ 22216880+  0+  0+  0+  0+
+---+---+---+---+---+
+  0+  0+  0+  0+  0+
+---+---+---+---+---+
+  0+  0+  0+  0+  0+
+---+---+---+---+---+
+  0+  0+  0+  0+  0+
+---+---+---+---+---+
+  0+  0+  0+  0+  0+
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: A pointer-to-pointer is not a two-dimensional array. You'd be better off allocating a real 2D array and obtaining a pointer to its first element, like this: `int (*arr)[y] = malloc(x * sizeof(*arr));`. Apart from that, why are you allocating one extra byte? It seems to serve no purpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line, you are making a mistake

```
b->mark=malloc(sizeof(int)*n+1);
```

It should be

```
b->mark=malloc(sizeof(int*)*n+1);
```

Basically you are going to store the address of the int array in the first dimension, which could be different for every architecture. So you should you int*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve my problem. On windows with mingw the other line works well. Whatever....

Answer (score 0):

To save yourself a lot of time and debugging, either use a real two diemensional array as H2CO3 said in the comment, or a one-diemensional array with appropriate getter and setter.

```
struct t_brett {
    //Boardsize
    int boardSize;  
    // Pointer for a 2-dimensional Array
    int *board; 
    //number of jump
    int lsgnr;
    //position of the knight Springers
    int x;
    int y;
} t_brett;

// somewhere in initialization code
board = calloc ( sizeof(int) * boardSize * boardSize );

int getValue(t_brett* brett, int x, int y) {
  if (x<0 || x>=boardSize) return -1;
  if (y<0 || y>=boardSize) return -1;
  return brett->board[x+y*boardSize];
}
```